# Could the proteome of E. coli be fluorescently labelled?

Tags: genomics, fluorescent-microscopy, protein-engineering

What proportion of the total number of proteins in E. coli could be fluorescently labelled for PALM/STORM imaging?

Comment: If (G)FP labeling is cumbersome or it changes diffusion co-efficients then you can try quantum dots or click chemistry based probes too. But as pointed out in the answer, you have to do one at a time. If I am not mistaken there are libraries with each protein GFP tagged (at least for yeast afaik there is one)

Answer (score 1):

One at a time, you could potentially label all of them.

If you're asking how many proteins you could label at once, your biggest limitation is probably your microscope. In order to distinguish between different types of proteins you need different color fluorescent labels (dyes, fluorescent proteins, etc). Even the fanciest fluorescent microscopes tend to be set up to excite/record labels in <10 distinct wavelengths.

In practice I've only seen experiments where there were tracking 3 distinct types of proteins at one time.